# I am unable to connect to my new BT router wirelessly with my laptop

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, connection

I am unable to connect to my new BT router wirelessly with my laptop.

Everything else connects to it - phone, tablet etc, therefore I don't think its the router. However, I am able to connect directly through a wired connection. I have the same problem when I try to connect to the internet in friends houses.

What I have tried:

- Checked that the 'wireless' switch on my laptop is on.
- When I go to the drop down menu on my tool bar I am not given the option to find / add a new Wi-Fi network.
- Some where in settings I have found a manual window for adding a network, which involves adding a mac address and various other information but this does not work either - maybe I am filling it out incorrectly, I used the details for the old router as a template.

My late husband set up our previous router and my wireless connection, however, he was VERY security conscious and I don't know how he has set my laptop up to be unresponsive to new wi-fi networks.

This is the version I am using: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Many thanks.

**Response to lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 terminal command:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:051b]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05
```

)

Does this help?**

WPA2 encryption is in use.

Comment: What is "BT router"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 BT = British Telecom, I believe.

Comment: Yep, BT is the name of the company who provided it when I changed ISP.

Comment: What encryption is in use? WEP/WPA/WPA2?

Comment: WPA2 encryption is in use